# KeyboardInterrupt not raised or caught in the case of broad Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

Could somebody explain to me the following. Lets take a look at the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while 1:
            x = 2+2
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('yo')
```

If I run this, wait for a while, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, an exception will be processed and the message `yo` will be printed.

If we change the code to catch a broad exception like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while 1:
            x = 2+2
    except Exception, e:
        print('yo')
        print(e)
```

Run it, wait for a while, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the KeyboardInterrupt exception will not be caught.

According to [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html):

> Python installs a small number of signal handlers by default: SIGPIPE is ignored (so write errors on pipes and sockets can be reported as ordinary Python exceptions) and **SIGINT is translated into a KeyboardInterrupt exception**. All of these can be overridden.

So, why in the second case is this exception not caught or even raised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot catch `KeyboardInterrupt` by catching [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) because the former inherits from [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException) only.  You can read about this in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt):

> exception `KeyboardInterrupt`
>
> Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally Control-C or Delete). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly.
>   Interrupts typed when a built-in function `input()` or `raw_input()` is
>   waiting for input also raise this exception. **The exception inherits
>   from `BaseException`** so as to not be accidentally caught by code that
>   catches `Exception` and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting. *(Emphasis mine)*

This means that you would have to do:

```
except BaseException, e:
```

But that is considered a bad practice.  It would be better to just catch `KeyboardInterrupt` itself like in your first example.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth noting that catching all BaseExceptions is even worst than catching all Exceptions ...

Comment: its a question for a separate thread, but will ask here. if I want to post-process ALL kinds of program termination (graceful shutdown) - the only way is to add handlers for all corresponding signals?

Comment: @dizpers - Well, if you want to catch _everything_, then catching `BaseException` should be fine.  I was saying if you just want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, then just catch `KeyboardInterrupt`. :)

Comment: If you want to catch everything, just use bare `except:`.

Comment: @kindall - Or that. :)  It is a force of habit for me to list at least _something_.

Comment: not all exceptions, but only termination signals such as SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL, etc